# Angular 2+ server-side rendering with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-universal

I encountered something debilitating.

I'm pretty far in a project right now, and it definitely needs to be rendered server-side at some point.

The webapp lets users upload pictures such as profile picture and also "regular" pictures.

I'm using Croppie from Foliotek (https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie) to do the cropping, which works well and is exactly what I need.

But Croppie relies on jQuery. Yesterday I found out that could be an issue if I want to make the app server-side rendered.

All the jQuery is used in **ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hooks**, so I'm hoping this makes it server-side rendering proof?

I know there is ng2-img-cropper available, but I'm not so keen to implement that one. BUT, if I can use ng2-img-cropper together with server-side rendering then I'll have to.

Or is there something far better I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery on server, with Node, AFAIK. Just browse npm and search for suitable module. And do not forget, that Node have no DOM implementation, so you need module for virtual DOM also.

For example, you can use [this jQuery wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jQuery) with [this DOM implementation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom). Example:

```
npm install jsdom
npm install jQuery

var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom
var myWindow = jsdom().createWindow()
var $ = require('jQuery')
var jq = require('jQuery').create()
var jQuery = require('jQuery').create(myWindow)

$("<h1>test passes</h1>").appendTo("body")
console.log($("body").html());
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address any of the *server-side rendering* concerns the OP is asking about. The idea that you may be able to use jQuery in a node application has nothing to do with this, really.

Answer (score 1):

I found out there is an Angular Universal (server-side rendering) starter project available:

https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

I cloned it and implemented Croppie as I did in my development version and everything works just fine!

So... I wonder why I've read multiple times that things will totally break if using jQuery in your Angular 2+ SSR project. Also Max Schwarzmuller told so in his lectures on Udemy. Anyway. I'm happy to have found everything still works.

Answer (score 0):

as i know, when ever jquery use "Window", ssr gets confused, because in server we don't have window(window is in browser). 
but normally, jquery works.